# Col plot: fill 100 - value

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a df, which gives the plot

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(group = c("Thriller", "Horror", "Action"), number = c(60, 50, 90))

ggplot(df, aes(group, number)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

But I want this

[image]

I tried tings with fill, but it does not give me the result. Does someone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
ggplot(data.frame(group = rep(df$group, 2),
                  number = c(df$number, 100 - df$number),
                  class = rep(c("B", "A"), each = nrow(df))),
       aes(group, number, fill = class)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(number, "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("dodgerblue", "gray30"), guide = "none")
```

[image]